# Website causes script error in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a single page Wordpress Website http://sophiance.com/

Owing to the nature of the website it has a log of assets like jquery plugins and images.

It seems to crash IE8 browser in all machines I have tried and at times hangs the computer as well.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [webapps.se]. Unless this is code you've written yourself, in which case you should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: IE 8 might crash in the case of malformed CSS (Multiline comment without the /*) / ..., does the page makes IE8 crash if you disable JS ? Does it crashes with the CSS disabled ?

Comment: @RelevantUsername i am using IE tester dont have IE8 so am not sure. any idea how to check that.

Comment: And if you correct the errors in the page, does it still crash? ([See validator results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsophiance.com%2F&charset=windows-1252&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices).)

Comment: By the way, a script error is not a crash.

Comment: @MrLister trying to debug and figure out which one. not able to debug

Comment: @HarshaMV The error message is quite clear: `http://sophiance.com/index.html` causes error on line 718. If this line is not a script line, it has an inline function call / function, and that invoked function has a syntax error. JS expects a variable name, but finds something else instead. Most common reason for this is a trailing comma in a object/ array literal, or an attempt to declare an object like: `var foo[n] = ...;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing comma in an object literal definition at line 717, and three more after it.

```
Cufon.replace('.articleReadMore', {
        hover: {
            color: '#0171a0'
        }, <--- Remove this
    });
```

Just remove the comma; IE8 didn't support trailing commas, but IE9+ and other browsers do.